# траблы с плагинами в go

Tags: golang, плагин

возникла ошибка

```
interface conversion: plugin.Symbol is *main.plug, not *main.plug (types from different packages)
```

**launcher.go**

```go
package main

import (
    "path/filepath"
    "plugin"
    "log"
    "os"

    "./plugins/basic"
)

func _check(err error) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

type plug struct {
    basic.PluginBase
}

func LoadPlugins(plugs *[]plugin.Plugin) {
    plugnames, err := filepath.Glob("./plugins/*/*.so")
    _check(err)
    for _, pname := range plugnames {
        newplug, err := plugin.Open(pname)
        _check(err)
        prepluginbase, err := newplug.Lookup("Plugin")
        _check(err)
        pluginbase := prepluginbase.(*plug)

        *plugs = append(*plugs, *newplug)
    }
}
```

**plugins/basic/main.go**

```go
package basic

type PluginBase struct {
    Commands    []string
    Description string
}
```

**plugins/ping/main.go**

```
package main

import (
    "../basic"
)

type plug struct {
    basic.PluginBase
}

var Plugin plug

func (p *plug) Setup() {
    // some stuff
}

func (p *plug) Run() {
    // some stuff
}

func main() {}
```

у типов абсолютно одинаковое тело, что ему не нравится?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В *Go* используется
[номинативная система типов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).
Так что ему всё равно, какие у типов внутренности.  Усли это два разных
типа, с разным *pkgpath*, то так он их и воспринимает.  Вам нужно
импортировать `plug` из одного и того же пакета.